# Unable to read a space delimited file

Tags: r, read.table

I am having issues reading this space delimited file into R with read.table. I am open to other working functions. Here is some data from the file. This is the header but it is formatted the same as the data.

`Date     Cusip     ISIN         Ticker   Exchange     Name                         Shares     Mkt Value    Weight ES Economic Sector                SubS SubSector                                        IND     Industry`

Sorry about that format, that is exactly how it appears in notepad.

So as you can see, it has different values between each "cell". But whenever I read the table into R, it puts all the data into one column.

Comment: Reading in your sample file works fine for me, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Like I said I tried read.table. What'd you do? And it might just be because I have another 100 rows.

Comment: I just used read.table("filename.txt"), using the default parameters, and it gave me a table with 17 rows just fine

Comment: @CactusWoman Alright. Now I'm getting this error `line 1 did not have 24 elements` . And @RuthgerRighart that'd probably work if there weren't different number of spaces between each columns.

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at the whole file, but it sounds like maybe your table has different numbers of rows. Can you provide a link to the whole file?

Comment: @NealC: change sep="" which stands for any number of spaces

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I am getting the same error as before. ` line 1 did not have 22 elements` just a different number of elements. Line 1 is provided in the question.

Comment: @NealC could it be that some of your variable names contain spaces in itself, for ex. "Mkt Value"? That may be a problem.

Comment: Yes. I'll go ahead and add that to the question itself. But I did state that in a comment above. @RuthgerRighart

Comment: Where did your data come from? You're going to have problems if your strings are not quoted (Mkt value, for instance, is treated as two variables because of the space). Is it, for instance, an excel file that you saved as a tab-delimited file? If so, you can save it in a nicer format that has quoted text cells.

Comment: @NealC. Perhaps a workaround is then to read in the data without header (header=FALSE) and read in the columnnames later.

Comment: I've found a workaround...almost. I'll post it once I finish it. Thank you to both @RuthgerRighart and CactusWoman .. It won't let me tag both.